# Juntar dois itens de uma IList em um só item pelo Id

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lista, expressões-lambda

Na minha classe tem:

```
Id 
Venda 
Devolucao
```

Tenho uma `IList` dessa classe, e nessa `IList` tem

```
[0] classe Id = 100, Venda = 230.00, Devolucao = 0;
[1] classe Id = 100, Venda = 0, Devolucao = 50.00;
[2] classe Id = 101, Venda = 515.00, Devolucao = 0;
[3] classe Id = 101, Venda = 0, Devolucao = 42.00;
```

Como juntar essas informações pelo Id? Para ficar:

```
[0] classe Id = 100, Venda = 230.00, Devolucao = 50.00;
[1] classe Id = 101, Venda = 515.00, Devolucao = 42.00;

class VendaDevolucao
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual double Venda { get; set; }
    public virtual double Devolucao { get; set; }
}

IList<VendaDevolucao> vendas = new List<VendaDevolucao>();

VendaDevolucao venda1 = new VendaDevolucao();
venda1.Id = 100;
venda1.Venda = 230.00;
venda1.Devolucao = 0;
vendas.Add(venda1);

VendaDevolucao venda2 = new VendaDevolucao();
venda2.Id = 100;
venda2.Venda = 0;
venda2.Devolucao = 50.00;
vendas.Add(venda2);

VendaDevolucao venda3 = new VendaDevolucao();
venda3.Id = 101;
venda3.Venda = 515.00;
venda3.Devolucao = 0;
vendas.Add(venda3);

VendaDevolucao venda4 = new VendaDevolucao();
venda4.Id = 101;
venda4.Venda = 0;
venda4.Devolucao = 42.00;
vendas.Add(venda4);
```

Comment: Coloque o código que já tem. [mcve]. Especifica melhor o que seria juntar.

Comment: coloquei um exemplo... não é a situação real, só quis deixar de um modo mais genérico

Comment: "agregar" as informações onde o Id for igual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faz um **agrupamento** com [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397906.aspx) `(System.Linq)`, use o `Id` para agrupar e some os valores dos outros dois campos:

***Exemplo***

```
var items = vendas.GroupBy(c => c.Id)
      .Select(s => new {
         Id = s.Key,
         Venda = s.Sum(v => v.Venda),
         Devolucao = s.Sum(d => d.Devolucao)
      }).ToList();
```

[***Demo***](https://ideone.com/fork/TmyaeC)

***ou***

```
var items = vendas.GroupBy(c => c.Id)
      .Select(s => new VendaDevolucao  {
         Id = s.Key,
         Venda = s.Sum(v => v.Venda),
         Devolucao = s.Sum(d => d.Devolucao)
      }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Com LINQ pode fazer isto:

```
    var junta = vendas.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
        .Select(x => new {
            Id = x.First().Id,
            Venda = x.Sum(v => v.Venda),
            Devolucao = x.Sum(v => v.Devolucao)
        });
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9SCaVZ). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ie3bcc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/SumLists.cs).